# put file into firehose data stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, data-stream, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Using this command, I can put data into my firehose stream. It automatically creates a file in the destination bucket and puts the data value in that file. The file has an unknown data type.

```
aws firehose put-record --delivery-stream-name mystream --record="{\"Data\":\"1\"}"
```

Instead of this, is it possible to push a file (for example .csv or json to the data stream? Such that the file is placed in the destination bucket with the correct file type.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly its not possible. Firehose creates and has full control over its files in S3. You would have to setup a lambda function which would get automatically triggered and modify the Firehose files for you.